# how can i start making my own virtual keyboard program using lazarus in linux

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lazarus

I am new in using lazarus in linux, We  actually have a project that we need to make our own virtual keyboard. We really don't know where to start. Can anybody have an idea please share to us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I need a vrtual keyboard. Do you have success with it. Will it possible you share it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new project
2. Add new required package [`lazmouseandkeyboardinput`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/MouseAndKeyInput)
3. Add to uses section of the main form unit `MouseAndKeyInput`
4. Put to the main form TPanel (named pnlVK in my example) and TEdit (named Edit1 in my example)

Code of the main form:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes, Forms, Controls, ExtCtrls,
    Buttons, StdCtrls, MouseAndKeyInput;

type

    { TForm1 }

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Edit1: TEdit;
        pnlVK: TPanel;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure CapsChange(Sender: TObject);
        procedure VKClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure SendVK(Data: PtrInt);
    private
        { private declarations }
    public
        { public declarations }
    end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.VKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Asynchrouse call to ensure that will no any collisions with LCL code
    Application.QueueAsyncCall(@SendVK, (Sender as TSpeedButton).Tag);
end;

procedure TForm1.SendVK(Data: PtrInt);
begin
    // Emulate key press
    KeyInput.Press(Integer(Data));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    b: TSpeedButton;
    cb: TSpeedButton;
    i: Byte;
    c: Char;
begin
    // Create virtual numeric keys from 0 to 9
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
        c := Chr(i + Ord('0'));
        b := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
        b.Caption := c;
        b.Tag := Ord(c);
        b.OnClick := @VKClick;
        b.Parent := pnlVK;
        b.Top := 4;
        b.Left := i * (b.Width + 2) + 2;
    end;

    // Create virtual alpha keys from a to j
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
        // Use upper case characters for key codes
        c := Chr(i + Ord('A'));
        b := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
        b.Caption := c;
        b.Tag := Ord(c);
        b.OnClick := @VKClick;
        b.Parent := pnlVK;
        b.Top := 8 + b.Height;
        b.Left := i * (b.Width + 2) + 2;
    end;

    // For changing shift states (Shift, Alt, Ctrl) see methods
    // procedure Apply(Shift: TShiftState);
    // procedure Unapply(Shift: TShiftState);
    // of the KeyInput object

    cb := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
    with cb do
    begin
        Caption := 'Caps Lock';
        Width := Self.Canvas.TextWidth(Caption) + 8;
        AllowAllUp := True;
        GroupIndex := 1;
        Parent := pnlVK;
        Top := 4;
        Left := (b.Width + 2) * 10 + 4;
        Down := False;
        OnClick := @CapsChange;
    end;

    // Form & controls layout
    pnlVK.Align := alBottom;
    Self.Width := cb.Left + cb.Width + 10;
    pnlVK.Height := b.Height * 2 + 10;
    Edit1.Top := 4;
    Edit1.Left := 4;
    Edit1.Width := Self.Width - 8;
    Self.Height := Edit1.Height + pnlVK.Height + 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.CapsChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Set shift state depending of the Caps Lock virtual key state
    if (Sender as TSpeedButton).Down then
        KeyInput.Apply([ssShift])
    else
        KeyInput.Unapply([ssShift]);
end;

end.
```

Remember that key strokes will receive currently focused control.

Some articles for reading:
[MouseAndKeyInput](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/MouseAndKeyInput)
[Asynchronous Calls](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Asynchronous_Calls)
[Lazarus forum  Topic: Creating Virtual Keyboard](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18797.0)

Hope this will helpful.